# How to convert caf to mp3/amr?

Tags: iphone, mp3, lame, caf

Is there a way to convert the iphone record .caf files to .mp3 or amr files? Because the caf file need to upload, and server part can't use this format.
I am not familiar with audio processing. Here is my conclude :

1. The iphone sdk don't have a direct api to do this. We can only change the encoding format (AAC, IMA, iLBC, ALAC), see ACAudioFileConvert Demo. But it's still a caf file, I want to know if I can convert to mp3 by this.
2. Some guys suggest to use ["LAME" api](http://lame.sourceforge.net/). Is anyone successful to use it in ios? Can anyone share a simple demo ? 
   Someone said it may cause a licence issue ?

Can anyone give me any advice ? 
Sincere thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:
    int read, write;

```
FILE *pcm = fopen("file.caf", "rb");
FILE *mp3 = fopen("file.mp3", "wb");
const int PCM_SIZE = 8192;
const int MP3_SIZE = 8192;

short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE*2];
unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];

lame_t lame = lame_init();
lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 44100);
lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_default);
lame_init_params(lame);

do {
  read = fread(pcm_buffer, 2*sizeof(short int), PCM_SIZE, pcm);
  if (read == 0)
    write = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
  else
    write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
  fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, 1, mp3);
} while (read != 0);

lame_close(lame);
fclose(mp3);
fclose(pcm);
```

Comment: Its converting to mp3 file.. but the data is having only the noise