# 'Media Format' for '.caf' file in Amazon Transcribe

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, amazon-transcribe, expo-av

I have a React Native (Expo) app which captures audio using the `expo-av` library.

It then uploads the audio file to Amazon S3, and then Transcribes that in Amazon Transcribe.

For Android , i save the audio as a '.m4a' file,  and call the Amazon Transcribe API as :

```
transcribe_client.start_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName = job_name,
                                          Media={'MediaFileUri' : file_uri},
                                          MediaFormat='mp4',
                                          LanguageCode='en-US')
```

What should the 'MediaFormat' be for upload from  an iOS device, which will typically be a '.caf' file ?

Amazon Transcribe only allows these media formats

```
 MP3, MP4, WAV, FLAC, AMR, OGG, and WebM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Create an API wich does the conversion for you.
   You can easly create one using for example the [FFMPEG](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) python library.
2. Use an already made API.
   By using the [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/caf-converter) API you can convert the file with ease, but only if you pay for it.
3. Use an different library to record the IOS audio.
   There's an module called [react-native-record-audio-ios](https://github.com/rhaker/react-native-record-audio-ios) wich is made entirely for IOS and record audio in `.caf`, `.m4a`, and `.wav`.
4. Use the [LAME api](https://lame.sourceforge.io/) to convert it.
   As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389062/how-to-convert-caf-to-mp3-amr), you can convert a `.caf` file into a `.mp3` one by probably creating a [native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) wich would run this:

```objectivec
FILE *pcm = fopen("file.caf", "rb");
FILE *mp3 = fopen("file.mp3", "wb");
const int PCM_SIZE = 8192;
const int MP3_SIZE = 8192;

short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE*2];
unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];

lame_t lame = lame_init();
lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 44100);
lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_default);
lame_init_params(lame);

do {
  read = fread(pcm_buffer, 2*sizeof(short int), PCM_SIZE, pcm);
  if (read == 0)
    write = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
  else
    write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
  fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, 1, mp3);
} while (read != 0);

lame_close(lame);
fclose(mp3);
fclose(pcm);
```

5. Creating an native module who runs [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119422/convert-caf-file-to-wav-file-with-progress-bar-in-ios) `objective-c` code:

```objectivec
-(void) convertToWav
{
// set up an AVAssetReader to read from the iPod Library

NSString *cafFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"caf"];

NSURL *assetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:cafFilePath];
AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];

NSError *assetError = nil;
AVAssetReader *assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:songAsset
                                                           error:&assetError]
;
if (assetError) {
    NSLog (@"error: %@", assetError);
    return;
}

AVAssetReaderOutput *assetReaderOutput = [AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput
                                          assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks:songAsset.tracks
                                          audioSettings: nil];
if (! [assetReader canAddOutput: assetReaderOutput]) {
    NSLog (@"can't add reader output... die!");
    return;
}
[assetReader addOutput: assetReaderOutput];

NSString *title = @"MyRec";
NSArray *docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [docDirs objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *wavFilePath = [[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent :title]
                         stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"wav"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:wavFilePath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:wavFilePath error:nil];
}
NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:wavFilePath];
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:exportURL
                                                      fileType:AVFileTypeWAVE
                                                         error:&assetError];
if (assetError)
{
    NSLog (@"error: %@", assetError);
    return;
}

AudioChannelLayout channelLayout;
memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                nil];
AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                          outputSettings:outputSettings];
if ([assetWriter canAddInput:assetWriterInput])
{
    [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];
}
else
{
    NSLog (@"can't add asset writer input... die!");
    return;
}

assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;

[assetWriter startWriting];
[assetReader startReading];

AVAssetTrack *soundTrack = [songAsset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];
CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake (0, soundTrack.naturalTimeScale);
[assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime: startTime];

__block UInt64 convertedByteCount = 0;
dispatch_queue_t mediaInputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);

[assetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:mediaInputQueue
                                        usingBlock: ^
 {

     while (assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
     {
         CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer = [assetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
         if (nextBuffer)
         {
             // append buffer
             [assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer: nextBuffer];
             convertedByteCount += CMSampleBufferGetTotalSampleSize (nextBuffer);
             CMTime progressTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(nextBuffer);

             CMTime sampleDuration = CMSampleBufferGetDuration(nextBuffer);
             if (CMTIME_IS_NUMERIC(sampleDuration))
                 progressTime= CMTimeAdd(progressTime, sampleDuration);
             float dProgress= CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime) / CMTimeGetSeconds(songAsset.duration);
             NSLog(@"%f",dProgress);
         }
         else
         {

             [assetWriterInput markAsFinished];
             //              [assetWriter finishWriting];
             [assetReader cancelReading];

         }
     }
 }];
}
```

But, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859151/convert-caf-to-mp3-on-the-iphone):

> Since the iPhone shouldn't really be used for processor intensive things such as audio conversion.

So i recommend you the third solution, because it's easier and doesn't look like an intensive task for the Iphone processor.

Comment: I am trying to avoid use of native modules, since i want the convenience of Expo.

Comment: I could also try to set the 'RecordingOptions' in Expo to be m4a for Android, and something suitable for AWS for iOS.